# My SVG graphics don't look as good in Unity as they do in my web brower

Tags: unity, image, svg

I thought had an easy solution to getting nice smooth edges on all of my images: export them to .svg and then use Unity's new SVG importer package. However, my svg images don't really look better once they get into Unity. They don't look worse than my .png images but they don't look as nice as they do when I'm looking at them in a web browser or photo viewer.

Why is that?
And is there a simple way to fix that?

I did try out as a 'Textured Sprite' instead of a 'Vector Sprite' and noticed some quality differences messing around with Sample size and Filter mode but I wasn't able to get the .svg images to look as good as they do in a regular image viewer.

ETA images:

SVG image in a viewer or web browser (This is ideal):
[image]
SVG image in Unity when object is close. It's okay but not as good. A little fuzzy plus it adds some random notches:
[image]
SVG image in Unity when object is far. More fuzzy:
[image]

PNG image in Unity when object is close. Very good:
[image]

But PNG image in Unity when object is far. Very fuzzy:
[image]

Comment: Don't forget to include image examples so we can see exactly what quality issues you're trying to solve.

Comment: Okay I added images of the ideal, the SVG images of the object near and far, and the PNG images of the object near and far. If I could get the close up quality of the PNG with the far away quality of the SVG I'd be happy. I might even be satisfied with just the SVG except that there doesn't appear to be the capability of importing an SVG sprite sheet which might add an extra layer of difficulty without the pay off of really crisp images.

Comment: Regarding the PNG image. Do you have any idea why the quality would vary so dramatically between the object up close and the object far (on the plane)?

Answer (score 1):

This is not a true answer but I'm posting this in case is helps someone.

I have decided to stick with .png for now. As yet I don't see enough of an image-quality improvement with .svg.  (If someone has figured it out though please post!)

2 things that have helped me though:

- In doing my own basic graphics, setting the initial graphic setting to 600 dpi rather than 300 dpi helped moderately in certain cases.
- If you have control over the look of the images, it appears that having an outline as part of the image seems to call extra attention to the jagged edges that appear, so consider avoiding them.

Wish I had a better answer. If I find one, I will update.

Answer (score 1):

Your PNG problem could be mitigated by enabling mip-maps and using trilinear filtering.

Answer (score 0):

**Unity 2018+**

You need to import the Vector Graphics package.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52562020/how-to-import-svg-to-unity-2018-2

> In order to import SVG with Unity 2018.2, you need to import the
>   package Vector Graphics with the new Package Manager (you can find it
>   in the menu Window > Package Manager).
>
> Then, you can import any SVG in the project by copying it in the
>   project's folder.
>
> Beware of the options in the inspector, the Generated Asset Type
>   controls the render mode, there are 3 modes: Vector sprite (default),
>   Textured sprite, Texture2D.

---

**Unity 2017-**

Unity does not natively support vector graphics, so you will need to use another format.

Comment: By my reading, it looks like OP is already using the Vector Graphics package. Did you have a recommended configuration to offer to improve the look of assets imported with this package?

Comment: @DMGregory nope. Just lazy reading on my part.

Comment: I think I'll leave the answer up anyways. It doesn't answer the OP question, but I think it may still be useful to a passerby.